# Regressors in active set degenerate error

Tags: r, machine-learning, shap

I would like to know how to solve the error.
I tried running the following code in R:

```
library("DALEX")
 library(shapper)
 library("randomForest")
set.seed(123)
 model_rf <- randomForest(x = exprs_fullmodel, y = group2)
 p_function <- function(model, data) predict(model, newdata = data, type = "prob")
 ive_rf <- individual_variable_effect(model_rf, data = exprs_fullmodel, predict_function = p_function, new_observation = exprs_fullmodel[1:2,], nsamples = 40)
```

I get the following error:

```
Regressors in active set degenerate. Dropping a regressor, after 12 iterations, i.e. alpha=3.990e-03, with an active set of 12 regressors, and the smallest cholesky pivot element being 2.107e-08. Reduce max_iter or increase eps parameters.
Early stopping the lars path, as the residues are small and the current value of alpha is no longer well controlled. 22 iterations, alpha=4.896e-03, previous alpha=4.484e-03, with an active set of 13 regressors.
100%|##########| 2/2 [00:00<00:00,  2.16it/s]Error in 1:nrow(new_data) : argument of length 0
In addition: Warning message:
In new_data$`_id_` <- c(1:nrow(new_data)) : Coercing LHS to a list
```

#############################################################################
The structure of my df is:

```
str(exprs_fullmodel)
 num [1:40, 1:196] -242725 664323 205022 361526 50264 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:40] "ID_1" "ID_2" "ID_3" "ID_4" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:196] "RP_neg_502_8606a15_343" "RP_neg_509_3864a10_653" "RP_neg_181_0508a3_017" "HILIC_pos_729_5911a0_959" ...

str(group2)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "control","test": 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 ...
```

Please let me know how to solve this error.

Comment: https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/379 I also get the same error message and hasn't figured out why. I see an explanation on github. It seems that there are correlated features in the feature matrix.